# What are some ways to solve $\frac{dx}{dt} = x + 1, x(0) = x_o$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, mathematical-modeling

I want to solve a simple ODE

$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = x + 1, x(0) = x_o$

I currently know of three ways to solve this from the top of my head:

1. Method of integrating factors, multiple entire expression by $e^{-t}$
2. Laplace transform
3. Separation of variables, divide both sides by $x+1$ then integrate both sides

I think there is a method just by guessing. However, I have forgotten the rule for guessing the solution of non-homogeneous equations such as this one.

Have I missed anything else?

Comment: What is the point of this question? Just making a list of methods that could work doesn't seem very useful (I could mention 5 methods that could work, but which is definitely not the best way of approach this particular problem). Trying to understand which methods are useful in which cases on the other hand would be a better question IMO. If you could clarify what your intent is then it would be easier for people to give better answers.

Comment: You can try series expansion

Comment: @Winther I want to learn math

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiate twice and obtain $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{dx}{dt}$. So we know that $\frac{dx}{dt}=c\cdot exp(t)$. Hence $x=c\cdot \exp(t) + d$. Now solve for $c$ and $d$.

Comment: Nice, this is harder than mine in this case, but works for polynomial inhomogeneities :)

Comment: (your final expression for $x$ is off, it should be $x = c \exp(t) + d$)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=x+1$. Then Suddenly, its an exponential
$$ X' = X ,\quad X(0) = x_0+1$$
So I guess we should write down the final answer
$$x(t) = (x_0+1)e^t-1$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $ \frac {dx}{dt} $ = x+1
Just rearrange a bit: (taking care that x $\neq   $ -1)
$$ \frac{dx}{x+1} = dt $$
Now, integrate on both sides:
you get $$ln(x+1)=t+c$$
or $$t=ln(x+1)-c $$  where **c** is a constant.

Also, given that x(0)=$x_0$
put x=0 in this equation.
$$x_0=ln(0+1)-c$$
i.e. $$x_0=-c$$
or, $$c=-x_0$$
put c back to our equation: 
$$ln(x+1)=t-x_0$$
So, $$t=ln(x+1)+x_0$$
is the answer.

Comment: This is just the execution of variant 3, it does not add a different solution method.

Comment: variant 3 ? did i post something incorrect?

Comment: No, the solution is correct, it just does not answer the question. Variant 3 in the question was given as separation of variables, exactly what you did.

Comment: ok...got it. actually i didn't learn variant 2 yet...

Comment: and variant 1 is a bit trickier...

Answer (score 0):

Guessing, or *method of undetermined coefficients*: The inhomogeneity in $\dot x-x=1$ corresponds to an exponential factor $0$ which is not a root of the characteristic polynomial, thus try $y_p=A$ to find $A=-1$ for a general solution $x=-1+Ce^{-t}$.

And fifth, you can always try a power series expansion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non homogenous (first order) linear ode.

$$x’-x=1$$

The characteristic polynomial corresponding to the homogenous equation is,

$$r-1=0$$

So $Ce^{rt}=Ce^{t}$ is the solution to the homogenous equation. Now we may use, say, the method of undetermined coefficients to solve for a particular solution.

Guess a constant for $x$, get that that  constant is $-1$.

So,

$$x=Ce^{t}-1$$

Comment: You’re right. Thanks! @Isham